# Drawing a particular commutative diagram

Tags: beamer, diagrams, commutative-diagrams

I can draw

[image]

using

```
\begin{diagram}
X &\rTo^{\gamma} &Y & \lDotsto & \varepsilon_2\\
\dTo^\alpha  &\ruTo^\beta & & &\\
Z& \lDotsto &\varepsilon_3
\end{diagram}
```

and the following declarations in the preample

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[small,nohug,heads=littlevee]{diagrams}
\diagramstyle[labelstyle=\scriptstyle]
```

Can someone please show me how to modify things to obtain the following variant of the original diagram?

[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome! Please make your code into a compilable example.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for the tip. Next time I'll do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind using xy-pic, the code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
  \xymatrix{
    {X} \ar[rr]^{\gamma} \ar[dr]^{\alpha}
    && {Y}\\
    {\varepsilon_{3}} \ar[r]
    & {Z} \ar[ur]^{\beta}
    & {\varepsilon_{2}} \ar[u]
  }% xymatrix
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

will produce

[image: commutative diagram]

For a tutorial on commutative diagrams using xy-pic, see section 8 of "Getting up and running with AMS-LaTeX", at `https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/amslatex-primer?lang=en`

Answer (score 4):

Here is the diagram with `diagrams.sty`; I drew the version with the standard arrow along with the `head=littlevee` version. The latter has disastrous results.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[small,nohug]{diagrams}
\diagramstyle[labelstyle=\scriptstyle]

\begin{document}

\begin{diagram}
X             &              & \rTo^{\gamma} &             & Y \\
              & \rdTo^\alpha &               & \ruTo^\beta & \uTo \\
\varepsilon_3 & \rTo         & Z             &             & \varepsilon_2
\end{diagram}

\diagramstyle[heads=littlevee]

\begin{diagram}
X             &              & \rTo^{\gamma} &             & Y \\
              & \rdTo^\alpha &               & \ruTo^\beta & \uTo \\
\varepsilon_3 & \rTo         & Z             &             & \varepsilon_2
\end{diagram}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I recommend using `tikz-cd` instead. The syntax is much easier and the result much prettier.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
X \arrow[rr,"\gamma"] \arrow[dr,"\alpha"] && Y \\
\varepsilon_3 \arrow[r] & Z \arrow[ur,"\beta"] & \varepsilon_2 \arrow[u]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the `tikz-cd` version with dotted arrows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
X \arrow[rr,"\gamma"] \arrow[dr,"\alpha"] && Y \\
\varepsilon_3 \arrow[r,dotted] & Z \arrow[ur,"\beta"] & \varepsilon_2 \arrow[u,dotted]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where to get diagrams.sty? Not available on ctan.org

Comment: @pzorba75 Indeed, it is only available on Paul Taylor's web site: http://www.paultaylor.eu/diagrams/

Comment: Although the `diagrams` package produces fine output, it contains a "time bomb" that renders the package unusable after a date preset by the author, so a new version has to be retrieved.  If the input for the project for which it is being used is expected to remain viable indefinitely, `diagrams` isn't the best package to choose.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I fully agree.

Answer (score 3):

LaTeX's built-in picture command isn't bad, though the trial-and-error to get things placed correctly is inconvenient. To get the following, use the code below.

[image: diagram.jpg]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}
\begin{picture}(150,50)
\put(0,0){$\varepsilon_3$} \put(70,0){$Z$} \put(140,0){$\varepsilon_2$}
\put(0,40){$X$} \put(140,40){$Y$}
\put(12,3){\vector(1,0){55}} \put(143,10){\vector(0,1){27}}
\put(13,38){\vector(2,-1){55}} \put(82,10){\vector(2,1){55}}
\put(13,43){\vector(1,0){120}}
\put(70,48){$\gamma$} \put(45,25){$\alpha$} \put(96,25){$\beta$}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two solutions: one with  `pstricks`, the other with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

With \texttt{pstricks}: \[ \psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.2, linewidth=0.5pt, nodesep=2pt, labelsep=2pt, rowsep=0.8cm, colsep=1cm, shortput=tab, linejoin=1}
\everypsbox{\scriptstyle}
\begin{psmatrix}
  %%%nodes
  X & & Y\\%
  \varepsilon _3 & Z & \varepsilon _2 %%%
  %%% arrows
  \ncline{1,1}{1,3}^{\gamma } \ncline{1,1}{2,2}^[tpos = 0.6]{\alpha }
  \ncline{2,1}{2,2} \ncline{2,2}{1,3}^[tpos = 0.36]{\beta } \ncline{2,3}{1,3}
\end{psmatrix}
\]

With \texttt{tikz-cd}: \[ \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=0.6cm]
X \arrow{rr}{\gamma }\drar{\alpha } & &Y \\%
\varepsilon _3 \rar & Z \urar[pos = 0.42]{\beta } & \varepsilon _2 \uar
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the `diagram` environment but for commutative diagrams I recommend using  [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) package and a `matrix of math nodes` to give:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,->,shorten >=2pt,looseness=.5,auto]
      \matrix (M)[matrix of math nodes,row sep=1cm,column sep=16mm]{
         X             &   & Y\\
         \varepsilon_3 & Y & \varepsilon_2\\
       };
       \draw(M-1-1)--node{$\gamma$}(M-1-3);
       \draw(M-1-1)--node{$\alpha$}(M-2-2);
       \draw(M-2-2)--node{$\beta$}(M-1-3);
       \draw(M-2-1)--(M-2-2);
       \draw(M-2-3)--(M-1-3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

I think the code is mostly self-explanatory, although familiarity with `tikz` will of course help:) One less obvious part, perhaps, is that the `(M)` in `\matrix (M)` says that the matrix coordinates should be referred to using the letter `M` together with the row and column indices. So if you instead had `\matrix (mat)` then you would refer to the coordinates as `(mat-1-1)`, `(mat-1-2)` etc.

There is also a [tikzcd](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) package but my simple mind cannot cope with the syntax it requires:)

Comment: the arrow at bottom left should be horizontal.  it's slightly tilted upward.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, you're right. The arrow goes between the centers of the corresponding nodes so it is not horizontal because `\varepsilon_3` and `Y` have different heights. This is clearly not what is wanted, but I do not see an easy fix. One way out is to add `\rlap{\phantom{$Y$}}` to the node but there ought to be a better way...

Comment: you might just add `\mathstrut` to the `\varepsilon` node.  not wonderful, but a bit more direct and scrutable than using a phantom (which, strictly speaking, should be `\vphantom`, which doesn't need an `\rlap`).