# arrow head wrong in diagram.sty by Paul Taylor

Tags: diagrams

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[silent,nohug,heads=littlevee,midshaft]{diagrams}

\begin{document}


\begin{diagram}[height=0.7cm]
H^{n}(k,(n)) &\rTo& H^{n}(k,Q(n)) &\rTo& H^{n}(k,D(n))
&\rTo& 0\qquad\qquad \\ 
\dTo^{} && \dTo^{\cong} && \dTo &&  \\
H_\eta^{n}(k,(n))&\rTo&H_\eta^{n}(k,Q(n))&\rTo&H_\eta^{n}(k,D(n))
&\rTo^{\text{onto}}& H_\eta^{n+1}(k,(n)).
\end{diagram}

\end{document}
```

And the output came as:

[image]

Both the marked arrow head position went wrong, is it possible to fix it? advise.

Comment: The package code is (intentionally) obfusciated, so it is difficult to modify anythng there. If you remove `head=littlevee` it looks better, maybe that is acceptable for your document.

Comment: The `littlevee` option is buggy, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/308352/4427 I don't think you can do much more that either removing the option or abandoning `diagrams.sty` altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `littlevee` option is *very* buggy; the tips are decently placed only in vertical arrows, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/308352/4427

There's not much more you can do than removing the option `head=littlevee`.

Debugging `diagrams.sty` is essentially impossible, because the code is obfuscated. As far as I can see, the arrows are boxed during package loading. That the `littlevee` arrows are inherently broken can be seen also in the manual itself (page 11)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can't find `diagrams` package in my TeX distribution, but you can get the same result with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz, diagrams={>={Straight Barb[length=5pt,width=5pt]}}}
\begin{document}
\[ 
\begin{tikzcd}[cells={anchor=west}]
H^{n}(k,(n)) \ar{r}\ar{d} & H^{n}(k,Q(n)) \ar{r}\ar{d}[swap, xshift=-2pt]{\cong} & H^{n}(k,D(n)) \ar{r}\ar{d}
&[10pt] 0 \\[10pt] 
H_\eta^{n}(k,(n)) \ar{r} & H_\eta^{n}(k,Q(n)) \ar{r} & H_\eta^{n}(k,D(n)) \ar{r}[yshift=2pt]{\text{onto}}
& H_\eta^{n+1}(k,(n))
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think it is not in it because of its strange license. I'd suggest doing what you're doing and use something more mainstream (and distributed)

Comment: @daleif I agree :)

Comment: @daleif I agreed what you said with tikz, but I have many diagrams (more than 150), so changing all to tikz may consumes more time

Comment: @MadyYuvi The `diagrams` package has a time-bomb in it that prevents its use after a certain date. When it's triggered, you have to install the new version. One day the author won't be around to provide a new release and you'll be stuck with a document that doesn't compile without error.