# Natural transformation commutative square

Tags: commutative-diagrams, xymatrix

[image]

How can I create this diagram with `xymatrix`?

The result of my try is

```
\[

\raise 23pt

\vbox{

\xymatrixcolsep{2.5pc}

\xymatrixrowsep{2.4pc}

\xymatrix{

A'\ar[d]_{u'}\ar[r]^{v}

\ar@{-->}[dr]_{\alpha}

&A\ar[d]^{u}

\\

B'\ar[r]_{w}

&B

&\hskip -30pt,

}

}

\]
```

But the result is an arrow from letters and I need arrow from arrows.

Answer (score 6):

Use a `3x3` matrix and then the dashed arrow starts at position `(2,1)` and ends at `(1,2)`.

You can also control the distance between cols and rows with `@C=` and `@R=`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
$\xymatrix@R=1cm@C=1cm{
  A' \ar[dd]_{u'} \ar[rr]^{v} && A \ar[dd]^{u} \\
     \ar@{-->}[ur]_{\alpha}   &&               \\
  B' \ar[rr]_{w}              && B
}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would like to show an alternative solution with `tikzcd`, because with this package there is no need to add additional columns, you can name the labels and draw arrows between them directly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[
    column sep=36pt,
    row sep=36pt
    ]
A' \ar[d, swap, "u'"{name=fromhere}]\ar[r, "v"{name=tohere}] & A\ar[d,"u"] \\
B'\ar[r,"w", swap] & B
\arrow[
    dashed,"\alpha", from=fromhere, to=tohere, swap, start anchor={east},
    end anchor={south}, shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt
    ]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you like the arrow tips similar to the `xymatrix` one, you can use `Straight Barb` (or any other style from TikZ), this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz, diagrams={>={Straight Barb[length=4pt,width=3pt]}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[
    column sep=36pt,
    row sep=36pt
    ]
A' \ar[d, swap, "u'"{name=fromhere}]\ar[r, "v"{name=tohere}] & A\ar[d,"u"] \\
B'\ar[r,"w", swap] & B
\arrow[
    dashed,"\alpha", from=fromhere, to=tohere, swap, start anchor={east},
    end anchor={south}, shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt
    ]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like, for my opinion, the tip of the vector of xymatrix. But In tikz-cd is there the same tip? I have seen many times the guide, but I have not finded nothing.

Comment: @Sebastiano I found something similar in one answer of mine: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/457119/101651. See my renewed answer.

Comment: Wonderful! I put your link between my favorite. :-)